# How to store a counter in an external file and load it in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a `file.txt` to store my 2 counters. After created it I want to load the counters in 2 divs.
I don't know how to replace this code with the location of the file.txt:

jQuery:

```
var counter1 = localStorage.getItem('bans') || 0;
var counter = localStorage.getItem('rans') || 0;
```

Because with this code the counters are different for all users, infact i used the "localStorage", But I would like that the counters are equal for all users.

I hope you understand. Thank you.

Comment: javascript is on client side and this is not a web server

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. JavaScript runs on the client. You can't directly create files on the server with JavaScript. You'll need to use AJAX or Web Sockets or some other technique to communicate to the server, and have the server keep track of the value of the counter.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you choose that way , but any way you can save for each user a text file based on users Id  on server side , and than you can parse data from that files as json from client side :

```
    $.get(localStorage.userid + 'data.txt', function (data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          alert(obj.bans);
    }
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use `localStoage`.

Comment: This is just an example that the text file holds the userID that was extracted from the local storage so the file on server side will be like ( "1data.txt , 2data.xt,3data.txt ) also no need he can still use one text file , and store all data as json. {"id":1,"bans":2,"id":25,"bans":6,etc....}